# Java - Check if a specific pixel in a picture is a certain color

Tags: java, image, colors, screen

I'm trying to make a program and I need to basically take the screen and check if a certain pixel, as in like coordinate (100,100) is a certain color code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599963/how-to-read-pixel-color-in-a-java-bufferedimage-with-transparency

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps? (from duplicate)

```
BufferedImage image;
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
        try {
            image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

            int color = image.getRGB(x, y);

            int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            System.out.println(red + " " + green + " " + blue);
        } catch (HeadlessException | AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```